# How can I achieve streaming data aggregation per batch using Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Spark Structured Streaming to read from a bunch of files coming into my system to a specific folder.

I want to run a streaming aggregation query on the data and write the result to Parquet files every batch, using *Append Mode*. This way, Spark Structured Streaming performs a partial aggregation intra-batch that is written to disk and we read from the output Parquet files using a Impala table that points to the output directory.
So I need to have something like this:

```
batch        aggregated_value
batch-1          10
batch-2           8
batch-3          17
batch-4          13
```

I actually don't need the batch column but it helps to clarify what I am trying to do.

Does Structured Streaming offer a way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you read [the guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html)? Did you try `groupBy` in Append output mode?

Comment: Hello Jacek, thanks for your reply. I have read the guide and tried different things so far. I cannot skip the watermark mechanism so that the aggregations are written to disk from the very first batch. Is that possible?

Comment: I think it is not possible.

Comment: Hello again, I found a piece of code that does what I need, but I'm not sure about how it will perform and if I can add whatever aggregation logic I need. The code uses a `KeyValueGroupedDataset` and `flatMapGroups`, like this: 
`val groupedDS = ds
      .groupByKey(id)
      .flatMapGroups{ case (id, iter) => Iterator((id, iter.length))}
      .toDF("id", "count")
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .outputMode("append")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()`
Then just change from console to file sink. What's your view on this?

Comment: Looks very promising. I must admit I've never used `flatMapGroups` before, but think I should change it.

Comment: Ok, I'll update here if I succeed